# pass the values in the baselayout.jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, tags, tiles

I have a scenario that,

i have to pass some values in the layout.jsp (it is the parent jsp), where tiles attributes are defined.

Now my question is that,

can i make it possible that i can retrieve any pojo value which is passed to any page that extends that layout.jsp.
I want to retrive that pojo values in layout.jsp

thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, how tiles is involved.  Anyways the value stack is accessible from any jsp. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

In front-end (in your case it is JSP), there are only 4 scopes to store an object: Application, Session, Request, and Page. Each of those has its own lifecycle, which should be self explanatory.

When you are simply storing an object as a request-attribute, then it is accessible for the whole page (parent template + tiles JSPs) but only for that request.

Tiles are there for template based designing. It wont help in passing data from one page to another.